# how to give dynamic path to fo:external graphic xsl

Tags: xsl-fo

The value I am getting for sp_sign(given below) I want to use it as src for fo:external graphic . I tried many things still no luck please help.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//**sp_sign**">
    <xsl:value-of select="**@value**" />
```

//

```
<xsl:variable name="src" select="//sp_sign" />
<fo:external-graphic baseline-shift="super" **src="${src}"** content-height="80px" content-width="80px"/>
</fo:block>
```

Thanks in advance
Regards,
Manik Vashisht

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp try this

Answer (score 8):

I normally give the src attribute using the xsl:attribute tag

```
<fo:external-graphic>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
             <xsl:value-of select="$src" />
       </xsl:attribute>
</fo:external-graphic>
```

the src should look like: url('path/to/image')

Comment: It's a lot cleaner to use an AVT (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates). Example: `<fo:external-graphic src="{$src}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can add the image file like this too.
Where LOGO is XML value, using apache fop 2.1

```
<xsl:variable name="logo" select="LOGO"/>
<fo:block>
  <fo:external-graphic src="file:///{$logo}" />
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the variable between braces!

```xml
<xsl:variable name="logo" select="LOGO"/>
<fo:block>
  <fo:external-graphic src="{$logo}" />
</fo:block>
```

The result will be:

```xml
<fo:external-graphic src="https://ibb.co/kqSQ9z3"/>
```